# How handle progress in BackgroundTransfer DownloadOperation C++/WinRT

Tags: uwp, c++-winrt

I try handle progress of downloading file via BackgroundTransfer::BackgroundDownloader in c++/WinRT Windows 10 UWP App.

I read the documentation 10 times yesterday:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.iasyncoperationwithprogress-2.progress?view=winrt-19041#Windows_Foundation_IAsyncOperationWithProgress_2_Progress

but i cant implement this correct :(

this is my sample code (file downloading well, but if i put .Progress function i got error:
`Error  C2280   'void *winrt::Windows::Foundation::IUnknown::operator new(size_t)': attempting to reference a deleted function  NativeModuleSample`

code:

```
BackgroundTransfer::BackgroundDownloader downloader{ BackgroundTransfer::BackgroundDownloader() };
BackgroundTransfer::DownloadOperation download = downloader.CreateDownload(uri, destinationFile);
auto progress = download.StartAsync();

progress.Progress(Windows::Foundation::AsyncOperationProgressHandler<BackgroundTransfer::DownloadOperation, BackgroundTransfer::BackgroundDownloadProgress>(
    [=](Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperationWithProgress<BackgroundTransfer::DownloadOperation, BackgroundTransfer::DownloadOperation> const sender, BackgroundTransfer::BackgroundDownloadProgress args) {
        int progress_calc = (int)(100 * ((double)args.BytesReceived / (double)args.TotalBytesToReceive));    
    }
));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle progress of downloading file via BackgroundTransfer::BackroundDownloader, you can refer to the Scenario1_Download of the [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundTransfer/cpp/BackgroundTransfer) in GitHub.

Based on the sample about downloading, you can change your code `progress.Progress(…)`  to this:

```
progress.Progress(Windows::Foundation::AsyncOperationProgressHandler<Windows::Networking::BackgroundTransfer::DownloadOperation, Windows::Networking::BackgroundTransfer::DownloadOperation>(
    [=](Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperationWithProgress<Windows::Networking::BackgroundTransfer::DownloadOperation, Windows::Networking::BackgroundTransfer::DownloadOperation> const sender, 
        Windows::Networking::BackgroundTransfer::DownloadOperation args) {
               
            BackgroundDownloadProgress currentProgress = args.Progress();

            UINT64 percent = 0;
            if (currentProgress.TotalBytesToReceive > 0)
            {
                percent =(INT64)((double)currentProgress.BytesReceived * 100 / (double)currentProgress.TotalBytesToReceive);
            }
    }
));
```